# Best partition strategy for delta lake for job pipeline on structured streaming

Tags: databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks

In my scenario i have 2 Structured streaming jobs, one write to Delta lake table and second job read from the delta lake table process it and write to another table.

for structured streaming (which only has to pick new records inserted after last stream batch) what is the best option for partition i should create. If i use CreatedDateTime column in my table, does the next job reading from this table will use that partition. Since I am just using readstream(), i am not sure what partition it will be using.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data itself on what column you should use for partitioning. If your data is distributed proportionally along the dates, then yes CreatedDateTime would work (what does the histogram look like? Do you not have any "peak" times where a lot of data comes in?). However, if it is not, your primary key might be a safer bet.